# Is It Possible to Interact With the Windows in Mission Control?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mission-control

Is it possible to use the windows shown in Mission Control?

For example, let's say I have Safari window opened and I want to scroll the page up/down while in Mission Control - is that possible?

If it isn't possible - do you know an app that can do something similar?

EDIT: I should point out that when you focus on a window in Mission Control and you press Space, it enlarge the window. (not what I want, but it's useful feature of Mission Control).

Comment: dont think so. as far as I know what you are seeing there is more like an image than the window itself, so you have to focus on it / come out of mission control to interact with it.

Answer (score 2):

The only things you can do with them are move them to other desktops, select them from groups to bring them to the forefront, or drag files/copied text into them.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I've wondered about this myself too. Hypothetically it should be possible, since the window views are updated normally even while using Mission Control. In fact, in Tiger I was sometimes able to enter keyboard input into the top window if I held down a key while using Expose. However, I don't think the Mission Control service is programmed to send mouse input to the windows, so unless a talented developer writes an app of some kind, it doesn't seem to be possible with the current version of Mission Control.